# How to remove this array name in my output?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started studying php so everyone please bear with me. Anyway this is my problem. I want to remove the array thing on the output of my query.
**OUTPUT**

```
array(2) { ["FNAME"]=> string(5) "FName1" ["LNAME"]=> string(5) "LName1" }
array(2) { ["FNAME"]=> string(7) "FName2" ["LNAME"]=> string(7) "LName2" }
array(2) { ["FNAME"]=> string(7) "FName3" ["LNAME"]=> string(7) "LName3" }
```

I dont know how to remove the array thing there. T_T

**MODEL**

```
public function get_employee_teama()
{
$sql ="SELECT "
."FNAME, " 
."LNAME "
."FROM employees "
."WHERE employeeteam=2 ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result_array();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index()
{
 $data['title'] ="TEAM A";
 $data['employeeteam']= $this->emploteam_model->get_employee_teama();
 $this->load->view('employeeteamview',$data);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<?php foreach($employeeteam as $eteam): ?>
<li>
    <?php var_dump($eteam);?>
</li>
```

Sorry if I'm a little noob I'm very new to PHP.

Comment: var_dump is a debugging tool that shows you information about the variable you pass it.  You can just do something like $eteam['FNAME'].$eteam['LNAME'] if you want to just output the variables.

Comment: ah.. so is that the reason why I'm getting array like thing in my output?

Comment: thanks, that's it. Could you post as an answer?

Comment: I wrote out 1 way to reproduce the output without using var_dump.  I omitted the curly bracket wraps too since they indicated the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't your end goal, but if you are really just trying to reproduce that without the array part of the string produced by the debugging tool var_dump(), this should work:

```
<?php foreach($employeeteam as $eteam): ?>
<li>
    <?php echo "[\"FNAME\"]=> string(".strlen($eteam).") ".$eteam['FNAME']." [\"LName3\"]=> string(".strlen($eteam['LNAME']).") ".$eteam['LNAME'];?>
</li>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<?php var_dump($eteam); ?>` try `<?php echo json_encode($eteam); ?>` if you simply want a representation of your php array without the "Array" text.

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode($eteam,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>` makes it look a little neater.